# Make Public IP on Wired Connection Static on Debian 11

Tags: debian, ip

I'm trying to configure my LAN interface in such a way that whenever I am connected to it, all the outbound traffic from my computer flows through a static IP address. How do I go about this?

I have googled a lot about this but all I found were tutorials and blogs for setting the private IP address

Comment: Get a public IP address first then route it to your machine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.